# Android "Couldn't make a guess for" error for Data-Bindng

Tags: android

After enable databinding for our project and read some error like with my problem i can't resolve problem, i use simple library as `CustomEditText` on my layout and i get this error:

```
Cause: couldn't make a guess for xx.xxxxx.xxxxxxxx.Core.Libraries.libizo.CustomEditText
```

Library page [link](https://github.com/Rajagopalr3/CustomEditText)

then I'm not sure problem is on using this library or i have error on layout

my layout:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data class="xx.xxxxx.xxxxxxxx">

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="xx.xxxxx.xxxxxxxx.Views.login.viewModel.LoginViewModel" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/grey_10">

        ...

        <libizo.CustomEditText
                android:id="@+id/instagram_page_name"
                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:gravity="left|center"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLength="50"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:minHeight="35dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="javane_milioner"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_40"
                app:addTextChangedListener="@{viewModel.getUserAccountPageName}"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView24"
                app:libIZO_clearIconTint="@color/grey_500"
                app:libIZO_setBorderColor="#d4d2d3"
                app:libIZO_setBorderView="true"
                app:libIZO_setClearIconVisible="true"
                app:libIZO_setCornerRadius="4dp"
                app:libIZO_setPrefixTextColor="@color/colorAccent" />    
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

I test adding class attribute on  but i get this warning:

```
Unknown attribute class more... (Ctrl+F1)
```

application ViewModel class:

```
public class LoginViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private InstagramAccount instagramAccount;
    private LoginResultCallback loginResultCallback;

    public LoginViewModel(LoginResultCallback callback) {
        instagramAccount = new InstagramAccount();
        loginResultCallback = callback;
    }

    public TextWatcher getUserAccountPageName() {
        return new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                instagramAccount.setUserPage(s.toString());
            }
        };
    }

    public TextWatcher getUserPagePassword() {
        return new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                instagramAccount.setUserPassword(s.toString());
            }
        };
    }

    public void onLoginClicked(View view) {
        if (instagramAccount.isValidate()) {
            loginResultCallback.onSuccess();
        } else {
            loginResultCallback.onError();
        }
    }

}
```

My app `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.novoda.bintray-release'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xx.xxxxx.xxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        ...
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
}

/* IMPORTANT :
 * Be careful when update dependencies, different version library may caused error */

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    ...
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    cleanedAnnotations
    compile.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains', module: 'annotations'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Cause: couldn't make a guess for xx.xxxxx.xxxxxxxx.Core.Libraries.libizo.CustomEditText`

Remove `class="xx.xxxxx.xxxxxxxx"`.

It would be:

```
 <data>

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="xx.xxxxx.xxxxxxxx.Views.login.viewModel.LoginViewModel" />
</data>
```

**BTW**: it's not a good way to use textWatcher inside *ViewModel* while using *DataBinding*, You should use **[Binding-Adapter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters.html)** instead

Comment: @DolDurma Are you passing the `viewModel` value  from the fragment/activity ?

Comment: i created some class for MVVM. after changing layout for using data binding i rebuild project and i get error now

Comment: @DolDurma You need to set your binding value i.e `binding.viewmodel = yourViewModel`  like here : https://github.com/googlesamples/android-databinding/blob/master/TwoWaySample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/databinding/twowaysample/ui/MainActivity.kt

Comment: AndroidStudio don't know `ActivityLoginBinding` in my activity